# Go: Bank Transfer Simulation using Goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

For university, I had to implement a bank transfer simulation in Java. Having done that, I wanted to implement it in Go, because I heard a lot about Go's concurrency capabilities and wanted to try them out.

I have two parties, foo and bar. Each party has a list of bank accounts with a balance and a number for identification. Every of foo's accounts should transfer a certain amount to one of bar's accounts. Those transfers should be split up in smaller and less suspicious transfers, transferring one unit repeatedly  until the whole amount was transferred. At the same time, bar is  transferring the same amount back to foo, so that the sum of foo's and bar's accounts, respectively, should be the same at the beginning and at the end.

Here's my Account struct:

```
type Account struct {
    Owner string
    Number int
    Balance int
}

func NewAccount(owner string, number int, balance int) *Account {
    account := &Account{Owner: owner, Number: number, Balance: balance}
    return account
}

func (account Account) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%04d", account.Owner, account.Number)
}
```

This is the function/method the account has to run in order to receive payments (I implemented outgoing payments as payments of negative amounts):

```
func (account *Account) Listen(channel <-chan int) {
    for amount := range channel {
        account.Balance += amount
    }
}
```

And here's my Transfer struct:

```
type Transfer struct {
    Source *Account
    Target *Account
    Amount int
}

func NewTransfer(source *Account, target *Account, amount int) *Transfer {
    transfer := Transfer{Source: source, Target: target, Amount: amount}
    return &transfer
}

func (transfer Transfer) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Transfer from [%s] to [%s] with amount CHF %4d.-",
        transfer.Source, transfer.Target, transfer.Amount)
}
```

Here's the function/method that performs the payment in a bunch of micro payments over a channel to each account:

```
func (transfer Transfer) Execute(status chan<- string) {
    const PAYMENT = 1
    sourceChannel := make(chan int)
    targetChannel := make(chan int)
    go transfer.Source.Listen(sourceChannel)
    go transfer.Target.Listen(targetChannel)
    for paid := 0; paid < transfer.Amount; paid += PAYMENT {
        sourceChannel <- -PAYMENT
        targetChannel <- +PAYMENT
    }
    close(sourceChannel)
    close(targetChannel)
    status <- fmt.Sprintf("transfer done: %s", transfer)
}
```

And, finally, here's the actual program:

```
func main() {
    const ACCOUNTS = 25
    const TRANSFERS = ACCOUNTS * 2
    const AMOUNT = 5000
    const BALANCE = 9000

    fooStartBalance := 0
    barStartBalance := 0
    fooAccounts := [ACCOUNTS]*Account{}
    barAccounts := [ACCOUNTS]*Account{}
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        fooAccounts[i] = NewAccount("foo", i + 1, BALANCE)
        fooStartBalance += fooAccounts[i].Balance
        barAccounts[i] = NewAccount("bar", i + 1, BALANCE)
        barStartBalance += barAccounts[i].Balance
    }

    fooToBarTransfers := [ACCOUNTS]*Transfer{}
    barToFooTransfers := [ACCOUNTS]*Transfer{}
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        fooToBarTransfers[i] = NewTransfer(fooAccounts[i], barAccounts[i], AMOUNT)
        barToFooTransfers[i] = NewTransfer(barAccounts[i], fooAccounts[i], AMOUNT)
    }

    status := make(chan string)
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        go fooToBarTransfers[i].Execute(status)
        go barToFooTransfers[i].Execute(status)
    }

    for i := 0; i < TRANSFERS; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%2d. %s\n", i + 1, <-status)
    }
    close(status)
    fooEndBalance := 0
    barEndBalance := 0
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        fooEndBalance += fooAccounts[i].Balance
        barEndBalance += barAccounts[i].Balance
    }

    fmt.Printf("Start: foo: %4d, bar: %4d\n", fooStartBalance, fooStartBalance)
    fmt.Printf("  End: foo: %4d, bar: %4d\n", fooEndBalance, fooEndBalance)
}
```

As the stdout shows, all the transfers have been done at the end:

```
 1. transfer done: Transfer from [bar-0011] to [foo-0011] with amount CHF 5000.-
[other 48 transfers omitted]
50. transfer done: Transfer from [bar-0013] to [foo-0013] with amount CHF 5000.-
```

But money is either created:

```
Start: foo: 225000, bar: 225000
  End: foo: 225053, bar: 225053
```

Or lost:

```
Start: foo: 225000, bar: 225000
  End: foo: 225053, bar: 225053
```

So I thought (with my Java mindset) that the problem might be Account.Listen(): maybe Balance is read by Goroutine A, then comes Goroutine B, executing Account.Listen() completely, then Goroutine A goes ahead doing the calculation with the old value. A mutex might fix it:

```
type Account struct {
    Owner string
    Number int
    Balance int
    Mutex sync.Mutex
}

func (account *Account) Listen(channel <-chan int) {
    for amount := range channel {
        account.Mutex.Lock()
        account.Balance += amount
        account.Mutex.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Which works great... nine ouf of ten times. But then:

```
Start: foo: 225000, bar: 225000
  End: foo: 225001, bar: 225001
```

This is very strange. The mutex seems to help, because it works most of the time, and when it doesn't work, it's only off by one. I really don't get at what other place synchronization might be an issue.

Update: I am no able to prevent data race warnings when I implement Account as follows:

```
type Account struct {
    sync.Mutex
    Owner string
    Number int
    Balance int
}

func NewAccount(owner string, number int, balance int) *Account {
    account := &Account{Owner: owner, Number: number, Balance: balance}
    return account
}

func (account *Account) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s-%04d", account.Owner, account.Number)
}

func (account *Account) Listen(channel <-chan int) {
    for amount := range channel {
        account.Lock()
        account.Balance += amount
        account.Unlock()
    }
}

func (account *Account) GetBalance() int {
    account.Lock()
    newBalance := account.Balance
    defer account.Unlock()
    return newBalance
}
```

And I also access the Balance at the end like this:

```
fooEndBalance += fooAccounts[i].GetBalance()
barEndBalance += barAccounts[i].GetBalance()
```

As I said, the data race detecter now stays silent, but I still got some errors in roughly every 10th run:

```
Start: foo: 100000, bar: 100000
  End: foo: 99999, bar: 99999
```

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework (and thanks for saying so), here is a clue.

> I really don't get at what other place synchronization might be an issue.

Whenever you run into this question, use the [Go data race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html). It has a few things to say about your code.

[Edit]

Another problem:

```
fmt.Printf("Start: foo: %4d, bar: %4d\n", fooStartBalance, fooStartBalance)
fmt.Printf("  End: foo: %4d, bar: %4d\n", fooEndBalance, fooEndBalance)
```

You print foo twice, instead of foo and bar.

The real problem is that you run your Execute goroutines, and assume that their work is finished immediately:

```
for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
    go fooToBarTransfers[i].Execute(status)
    go barToFooTransfers[i].Execute(status)
}

for i := 0; i < TRANSFERS; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%2d. %s\n", i+1, <-status)
}
close(status)
```

Here, you consider the job done and move on to printing the result:

```
fooEndBalance := 0
barEndBalance := 0
...
```

However, the goroutines may not be done at this point. You need to wait for them to be over before being sure that the transfer is done. Can you find a way to do that by yourself?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of that tool Tooling seems to be quite mature now after 10 years of go.
One data race happens when I output the whole transfer object upon sending a log message to the status channel. I can avoid that.
Another problem seems to be the summation at the very end. But I don't understand why this should be a problem, since all channels have already been closed by then.

Comment: Now I created a GetBalance() function/method that uses a mutex around the acces to Balance. The data race detecter now doesn't detect any more data races. But they still happen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the logging issue. But I don't just assume that the work of the goroutines is finished immediately. They write back through the status channel (which happens TRANSFERS times) as soon as they're all done. And then they must be done, right?

Comment: When the message transfer is written to the status channel, you know that the last transfer message was written and received, not that is was processed. Trying to acquire a mutex allows the scheduler to move on to another thread, e.g. back to the routine that wrote the transfer, which then happily moves on. However, the transfer was not actually done. Note that I am not sure that this is _the_ issue you are facing; I do think that it is _an_ issue in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Zoyd, you helped me to point out the issue. The issue is that the status is reported without having waited for both Listen methods. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
func (transfer Transfer) Execute(status chan<- string) {
    const PAYMENT = 1
    sourceChannel := make(chan int)
    targetChannel := make(chan int)
    sourceControlChannel := make (chan bool) // new
    targetControlChannel := make (chan bool) // new
    go transfer.Source.Listen(sourceChannel, sourceControlChannel)
    go transfer.Target.Listen(targetChannel, targetControlChannel)
    for paid := 0; paid < transfer.Amount; paid += PAYMENT {
        sourceChannel <- -PAYMENT
        targetChannel <- +PAYMENT
    }
    close(sourceChannel)
    close(targetChannel)
    // new condition
    if <- sourceControlChannel && <- targetControlChannel {
        status <- fmt.Sprintf("transfer done" )
    }
}

func (account *Account) Listen(channel <-chan int, control chan<- bool) {
    for amount := range channel {
        account.Lock()
        account.Balance += amount
        account.Unlock()
    }
    control <- true // new
}
```

It looks quite clumsy to me. I try to improve on that, but the issue now seems to be gone.

Edit: I now tried to simplify the code a bit. It's now working and the data race detector doesn't complain anymore, even though I don't use methods to access the balance.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sync"
)

type account struct {
    owner string
    number int
    sync.Mutex
    balance int
}

func (acc *account) listen(transfers <-chan int, control chan<- bool) {
    for amount := range transfers {
        acc.Lock()
        acc.balance += amount
        acc.Unlock()
    }
    control <- true
}

type transfer struct {
    source *account
    target *account
    amount int
}

func (trans transfer) execute(status chan<- string) {
    const PAYMENT = 1
    sourceChannel := make(chan int)
    targetChannel := make(chan int)
    controlChannel := make (chan bool)
    go trans.source.listen(sourceChannel, controlChannel)
    go trans.target.listen(targetChannel, controlChannel)
    for paid := 0; paid < trans.amount; paid += PAYMENT {
        sourceChannel <- -PAYMENT
        targetChannel <- +PAYMENT
    }
    close(sourceChannel)
    close(targetChannel)
    if <- controlChannel && <- controlChannel {
        status <- "transfer done"
    }
}

func main() {
    const ACCOUNTS = 10
    const TRANSFERS = ACCOUNTS * 2
    const AMOUNT = 100
    const BALANCE = 1000

    fooBalance := 0
    barBalance := 0
    foo := [ACCOUNTS]*account{}
    bar := [ACCOUNTS]*account{}
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        foo[i] = &account{owner: "foo", number: i, balance: BALANCE}
        bar[i] = &account{owner: "bar", number: i, balance: BALANCE}
        fooBalance += foo[i].balance
        barBalance += bar[i].balance
    }

    fooToBar := [ACCOUNTS]*transfer{}
    barToFoo := [ACCOUNTS]*transfer{}
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        fooToBar[i] = &transfer{source: foo[i], target: bar[i], amount: AMOUNT}
        barToFoo[i] = &transfer{source: bar[i], target: foo[i], amount: AMOUNT}
    }

    status := make(chan string)
    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        go fooToBar[i].execute(status)
        go barToFoo[i].execute(status)
    }

    for i := 0; i < TRANSFERS; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1, <-status)
    }
    close(status)

    for i := 0; i < ACCOUNTS; i++ {
        fooBalance -= foo[i].balance
        barBalance -= bar[i].balance
    }
    if (fooBalance != 0 || barBalance != 0) {
        difference := math.Abs(float64(fooBalance)) + math.Abs(float64(barBalance))
        fmt.Println("Error: difference detected: ", difference)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Success: no difference detected")
    }
}
```